# Об алгоритме вывода типов рекурсивных функций

Tags: рекурсия, scala, f#, ocaml, теория-типов

В Scala не реализован вывод типов для рекурсивных функций, в качестве аргумента Кей Хорстман в своей книжки пишет что "Алгоритм Хиндли-Милнера не стабильно себя ведёт в языках с ООП". Но, например, в F# и OCaml реализован вывод типов для рекурсивных функций и возникают вопросы: что же тогда имел ввиду Кей Хорстман? Есть ли примеры программ на ООП языке в которых алгоритм даёт сбой(ошибка согласованности типов в рантайме при успешно пройденной проверке типов на этапе компиляции)? Или косяк именно в каких-то особенностях Scala?

Comment: Вам лучше задать этот вопрос на форуме по языку или его внутренностям. http://www.scala-lang.org/community/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Система типов *Scala* однозначно содержит [F \sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F-sub).
Вероятно содержит намного больше (это сейчас активное направление исследований у нас)
но уже в F \sub многие вопросы, и в том числе этот - неразрешимая задача.

[Ссылка](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3059&context=compsci) на статью

Если честно, я не знаю как это работает в *F#* и *OCaml*. Думаю они делают best-effort.